# run without screen refresh in python

Tags: python, refresh, screen

I am a new Python user. Before python i programed with scratch (blocks programing language).
Scratch had a function to let me make custom block without running screen refresh (very fast). Does Python have something like this because my tiles is generating to long and screen just fill up. Here is the code(I am using pygame):

```
win.fill((174, 106, 71))
for b in range(12):
    for a in range(16):
        win.blit((brick), (tx, ty))
        tx += 50
    ty += 50    
    tx = 0
```

[image]

but if I add # to win.fill(...)

then that happnend:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, I found the solution, I just need to add ty = 0 att the bottom.